# Don't stop evaluation on exception?

Tags: java, pointers, exception, null

I currently have quite a long list of OR conditions within an if statement. However, some of them may or may not be initalised.

Is it possible to instruct java to ignore null pointer exceptions and continue evaluating the rest of the conditions in the if statement instead of jumping to the catch?

I need to call a method on a list of objects to check for a certain value, but some of the objects might not be intialised.

Thanks

Comment: You should check each variable for null before comparing ex: `if((a != null && a == 1) || (b != null && b == 2))`

Comment: No there is no way to ignore NPE in this way you whant. You have to check if your variable is `null`

Comment: @Jens Yes there is see above...This will not ignore exception but bypass exception alltogether

Comment: Thanks for all the responses! I know how to check to see if it is null... I was just hoping there would be an easy way to ignore certain exceptions considering how im just performing an evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by checking for the value of the variable

```
if(value != null) {
   // execute code here
}
```

You can catch the exception, and continue executing other threads of the code. But this if block would simply just execute the code, and the NullPointerException won't be raised.

But remember, the code would only execute if the value is not a null. If the value is null, the code block would be *skipped*.

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge, no. You maybe should consider the [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), so nothing happens but you can continue to execute.

An example:

```
Object onull = new NullObject();
Object oreal = new RealObject();

if(onull.contains(xy) || oreal.contains(xy)) 
    ....
// the onull.contains() will always return true
// only the oreal instance will actually perform the contains check
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition should be something like this:

```
if((a != null && a == 1) || (b != null && b == 2))
```

This is just an example but you should check for null before testing if there is a chance a variable could be null...